# Каким образом начать использовать TDD в новом проекте?

Tags: test-driven-development

Начал писать новый проект. Решил, что буду использовать MVP.

- Есть требование на главном экране показывать список элементов.
- По нажатию на кнопку добавить нужно открыть редактор безымянного
  элемента.
- По нажатию на конкретный элемент открыть его на редактирование.
- В редакторе можно сохранить изменения, тоесть если это новый элемент
  то добавить в список, если редактируемый, то отредактировать.

Я прекрасно понимаю как написать приложение без TDD. Но я не могу понять с чего начать в данном случае используя TDD. Что бы архитектура выработалась сама с собой.

Comment: >Что бы архитектура выработалась сама с собой



Эмм..это как?

Comment: Кент Бек, не продумывает дизайн кода, а пишет тесты, потом самый простой код для прохождения теста. В итоге у него складывается оптимальный дизайн приложения. Ну не в этом суть. Я написал пример требований, помогите понять, с чего нужно начать?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Давайте так...
Я выдвинул требования, что вы начнете делать следуя методологии разработки через тестирование?

Answer (score 1):

TDD, если грубо, вносит одно условие: пишется интерфейс, затем на него пишется тест, затем интерфейс реализуется, и к реализации применяется ранее написанный тест. Все, что вам нужно для TDD - это настроить тестовый фреймворк, любой CI, убедиться, что все это работает, перед написанием каждого класса писать на него тест (*если тест нужен*), убеждаться, что тест заваливается на пустой реализации, писать код до тех пор, пока тесты не выполняться, отправлять в репозиторий и смотреть на рост зеленых цифр и code coverage. No rocket science.

Про

> Что бы архитектура выработалась сама с собой

имеется в виду, что когда применяется подобный подход к разработки, каждый класс расматривается атомарно, и, за счет написания тестов, *нормальный* девелопер выносит лишние зависимости, а оставшиеся корректно организует.

Comment: Я это и без TDD делаю, просто юнит-тест пишу потом.
Получается TDD мне ничем не поможет? Просто вроде как это модно, а я этим не пользуюсь.

Comment: Вы неправильно понимаете TDD. TDD - это не набор техник, TDD - это ***подход***, который специально ограничивает программиста для достижения им определенных результатов, меняется концепция написания кода. Вы либо принимаете этот подход, либо нет; он не дает вам прямого развития, как программиста, но в конце концов научит писать легко разделяемый код.

Comment: TDD - это test driven development. Разработка, направляемая тестированием. То есть сначала мы всегда пишем тест, потом пишем код. Это навык. Он вырабатывается практикой. Если постоянно ее практиковать длительное время, то получаться будет все лучше и лучше.